# History states and changing the url on the url bar

Tags: javascript, html5-history

HTML5 introduced some *really* neat tools to [manipulate the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history), namely the `history.pushState`/`replaceState` methods and the `onpopstate` event, so we don't have to rely on `location.hash`es to display a meaningful url for our web applications.

(Or better, we *won't* have to rely on hashes when the adoption of IE<10 will be negligible.)

Using the browser's back and forward button doesn't reload the page if the targeted state was created using `history.pushState`, even if the URL looks completely different.

However, unlike changing the hash, if the user changes the url from the browser's address bar, the browser *does* reload the page. Somehow I doubt there's an effective solution for this, but the question is: is there a way to prevent the browser to reload the page, and force it to push an history state instead?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so. AFAIK, manually entering an address in the address bar - unlike clicking a link, back/forward buttons, pushstate/popstate, and form submit - is defined as requesting a new page, unless you change a hash (like in the pre-html5 days).

Answer (score 1):

No. It isn't possible to interrupt the loading of new pages via the address bar (except for `unload` events, but they can only give you "Are you sure you want to leave the current page?" interruptions).

The real URLs should be handled by your server which should build the page into the expected state for that URL before delivering it to the client.

Comment: Thought so. The server's work should always be taken into account before planning to use `history` API, since - you know - an user could always paste an url into the address bar. But if the aim of `history` API is to provide a cool way to change the url without reloading the page, it feels like the goal isn't completely fulfilled.